# Laravel Sanctum XSRF-TOKEN Cookie not Getting Sent

Tags: nuxtjs, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel 8 and I've been trying to follow the sanctum documentation for [SPA authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication). I've already done setting up the necessary configurations required. The backend server is running on localhost with default port(80) while SPA client is running on localhost:3000. I'm using nuxt framework for client with axios to make a request.

The initial request should be made to /sanctum/csrf-cookie to initialize the CSRF protection cookie and here's what network traffic traffic shows

[image]

The second request is the actual request that should contain the cookies sent by the first request for the domain but it looks like the XSRF-TOKEN is being skipped. Here's what network traffic looks like

[image]

sanctum.php config file:

```
<?php
return [
    'stateful' => explode(',', env(
        'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1'
    )),
    'expiration' => null,
    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],
];
```

cors.php config file:

```
<?php
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*', 'localhost:3000'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => ['XSRF-TOKEN', 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

session.php config file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),
    'http_only' => true,
    'same_site' => 'lax',
];
```

I set this in nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  axios: {
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: 'http://localhost/',
  },
}
```

Can somebody tell me why the XSRF-TOKEN cookie is not getting sent back?

Thanks

Comment: No replies so far, can you share some more info? cors.php and session.php would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the problem was caused by nuxt configuration for axios module. I just replaced the field 'withCredentials' with simply 'credentials'.

This is now the updated nuxt.config.js:

```
axios: {
    credentials: true,
    baseURL: 'http://localhost/api/',
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my Nuxt/Laravel 8/Sanctum config.

Notice I've not included `'sanctum/csrf-cookie'` in `'paths'`, because I've changed the prefix for Sanctum in `sanctum.php`. I've also got my nuxt dev server on port 3050, which is what you'll see in my config. Change yours to suit (e.g. 3000).

```
cors.php

'paths' => ['api/*'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => [env('ALLOWED_ORIGINS')], 
    .env e.g.: ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://localhost:3050
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Everything in session.php is left default, but make sure you update your .env with the correct `SESSION_DOMAIN`.

```
session.php

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
'expire_on_close' => false,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
'table' => 'sessions',
'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),
'lottery' => [2, 100],
'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
),
'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    .env e.g.: SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),
'http_only' => true,
'same_site' => 'lax',
```

Everything in sanctum.php is default, make sure you enter the correct `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN` in your .env (example below). I've also added the line `'prefix' => 'api'`. This allows me to set a single baseURL in axios and call the `csrf-cookie` route via `http://localhost:3050/api/csrf-cookie`. See more about it [here](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/issues/74).

```
sanctum.php

'stateful' => explode(',', env(
    'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
        .env e.g.: SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3050
    'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1'
)),
'expiration' => null,
'middleware' => [
    'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
],
'prefix' => 'api'
```

Then on the frontend, I have set axios up with a baseURL and ensured `withCredentials` is set to `true`

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.API_BASE_URL;
    .env e.g.: API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000/api
```

Assuming you've made no other changes that contradict the settings above, this should work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you followed these guides and you're still having problems, as I did, you might have missed setting `SESSION_DOMAIN` in your .env file.

Open Laravel's .env file and add `SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost`

One more thing:
If you cannot access "/csrf-cookie" route for some reason and still need to call "sanctum/csrf-cookie/", but Axios is adding `/api` in front of your requests, then use this piece of code:

```
let myNewInstance = this.$axios.create({
   baseURL: 'http://localhost' //without /api at the end
});

myNewInstance.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your laravel app is running on 127.0.0.1:8000 and your SPA is running on localhost:3000 or localhost:8080 etc.

Make sure that you:

1. Set the session domain to localhost
2. Set the `supports_credentials` to `true` (cors.php)
3. Set `with_credentials` to `true` in your client
4. When you send requests to your backend, send it to localhost:8000 instead of 127.0.0.1:8000